# Execute program from a GUI file explorer, and don't spawn a terminal

Tags: c++, terminal, cross-platform, sfml

I'm writing a program that opens a window and displays some things on it. However, if I run it spawns a terminal window. However, I don't want a terminal if it is run by double-clicking the file. The only case where I want to keep a controlling terminal is if it is run by `./filename` Is there any way to do this? I am using sfml for GUI. Note that this should work on there OSes, so [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGXlkOJ6SzQ) will no work.

A potential solution is I fork program, and then kill the process spawned by the terminal, but I have no clue if that works or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't click on the executable directly and instead use a batch script which runs:

`editbin /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS <your_exe>`

You won't get a console pop-up.

Comment: I want a cross-platform solution. I also would prefer something in the code itself

Comment: I'm not sure that you can get a cross-platform solution to this problem. Happy to be corrected on this point.

Comment: Even if it's not cross-platform, at least I don't want to execute a batch script or something

Comment: Again, I don't think what you are asking is possible. The specific behaviour you are asking to changes is part of the OS, not your program. Your programs can easily find out whether it was launched from within a console, but at that point you won't be able to avoid opening a new console because this would have already happened.

Comment: Another question: I can change compile flags, just no batch files. I know how to do this on windows, but not linux/posix systems.

Comment: I haven't done this myself, but you can run daemon processes which run in the background without any console.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is already answered on multiple instances in the SFML forum. You can check it out [here](https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=10792).The answer here seems to be windows specific. Long story short: Simply change the subsystem to Windows and link it against sfml-main.lib. However, doing that kind of makes it windows specific. Even the Dev isn't really giving a very explanatory answer saying it has already been answered in FAQs and Tutorials but I couldn't find any post/tutorial. However, this seems to be the only working (somewhat cross-platform) solution there is(and is the one I use). Hope that helps.

Comment: If there is some way to do this on Linux, ill be fine too. I'm not using windows to write code (Don't want to compile sfml), and I'm using a Linux. Is there a way to specify a flag in g++ to make it terminal less?